# Countdown timer when link clicked

Tags: javascript, countdown

I'm trying to make a countdown timer.

I have a table with several rows and four columns. In column two, I need a timer that starts when you click on a link in column one. When the timer finishes, it will appear "available". Each row needs.

This is what I have.

```
<table width="798" border="1" cellspacing="15">
<tr>
  <th width="302" scope="col">Website</th>
  <th width="139" scope="col">Status</th>
  <th width="118" scope="col">Time (Minutes)</th>
  <th width="146" scope="col">WO</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Don't click here</a></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td align="center">5</td>
  <td align="center">0.5-1.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><a href="http://yahoo.com" target="_blank">Don't click me</a></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td align="center">720</td>
  <td align="center">0.5-1.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

Comment: Since SO is not a code writing service, I'd say this is Off topic or at least downvotable.It's tagged as javascript and doesn't contain a single line of js and is broadly described.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this would be setTimeout

While I am not a fan of w3schools, but they do everything in easy to read, so here is the link https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Also, I am not posting the exact code as you are new to programming, and the best way to learn is to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm not even close to being a programmer, in fact, I'm Manufacturing Engineer. I just thought I was going to be able to develop the code myself. Big mistake!!! Already tried to modify many available codes without success. I'll keep trying

Answer (score 0):

Steps overview:

1. In HTML, use onclick and pass `this` as a parameter to the function.
2. In JavaScript, define the function and get the element stored in the parameter.
3. Inside the function define the variable that will store the time remaining (in seconds). If you need many variables at once, store the values inside an object and use as key the id of your html row.
4. Use setInterval to start a loop that countdowns the variable that stores the time remaining.
5. Once the variable value reaches 0, display your "Available!" text and clear the interval.

This requires basic knowledge of:

- JavaScript
- DOM events
- Arrays/Objects
- Loops (look for window.setInterval() and window.clearInterval())
- DOM modification

If you are new to programming it will take you some time to do this, but you will gain a valuable knowledge.

Btw if someone provides you the code working and ready to copy&paste, take your time in understand each line and even write your own implementation based on the provided one.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm not even close to being a programmer, in fact, I'm Manufacturing Engineer. I just thought I was going to be able to develop the code myself. Big mistake!!! Already tried to modify many available codes without success. I'll keep trying.